# Not able to create a VPC in AWS using Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

Below is my code using the API to create VPC in AWS, but I am getting an error.

**Code:**

```
CreateAccessKeyRequest key = new CreateAccessKeyRequest();
BasicAWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials("", "");
key.setRequestCredentials(cred);
AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client();
System.out.println("Creating VPC.....\n");
CreateVpcRequest newVPC = new CreateVpcRequest("In");
newVPC.setRequestCredentials(key.getRequestCredentials());
String cidrBlock = "192.168.1.70/28";
newVPC.setCidrBlock(cidrBlock);
newVPC.setInstanceTenancy(Tenancy.Default);
AmazonIdentityManagementClient client = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(cred);
CreateVpcResult res = ec2.createVpc(newVPC);
Vpc vp = res.getVpc();
vp.setIsDefault(true);
String vpcId = vp.getVpcId();
System.out.println("Created VPC" + vpcId);
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:10540)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.createVpc(AmazonEC2Client.java:5709)
    at CreateUserRequest.main(CreateUserRequest.java:29)
```

Comment: The error message complains about a lack of credentials, and you do `new BasicAWSCredentials("", "")`?

Comment: I have hardcoded the credentials inside the BasicAWSCredentials Class, still the same error.

Comment: Why do you need the `CreateAccessKeyRequest` object here? Why not just use the `BasicAWSCredentials` object directly? Or even better, why not take all the credential handling out of your code, and use a credentials profile file or environment variables (according to [Providing AWS Credentials in the AWS SDK for Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/credentials.html))?

Comment: Of course i am using only the BasicAWSCredentials  class, getting the same error.

Comment: Does the answer below helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code snippet above.

First, it is a bad idea to hardcode an access key / secret key.  These should be stored in an external configuration file or an environment variables.  If this code is meant to run from an EC2 instance, you should use "Roles" and Instance Profiles instead.  This is clearly explained at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/credentials.html

That being said, if this is just for a quick test, let's assume hard coding access key and secret key is indeed a possibility, there are other problems at code level :

- you do not need to use `CreateAccessKeyRequest` as this is the API call to generate a new Access key / Secret Key
- your `AmazonEC2Client` has no reference to your credentials provider
- there is no need to set the credentials provider for the VPC Request itself
- `setInstanceTenancy` is not required, this is the default
- `vp.setIsDefault(true);` is useless.  If you want to create a Default VPC, make a request to our Support team, they will flag your VPC as the default one (see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/deleted-default-vpc/)

Here is a modified code sample that create a VPC

```
package com.stormacq;

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateVpcRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateVpcResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Vpc;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicAWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials("AK...OQ", "gH...tp");
        AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(cred);
        ec2.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

        System.out.println("Creating VPC...");
        CreateVpcRequest newVPC = new CreateVpcRequest("In");

        newVPC.setCidrBlock("192.168.1.70/28");
        CreateVpcResult res = ec2.createVpc(newVPC);
        Vpc vp = res.getVpc();

        String vpcId = vp.getVpcId();
        System.out.println("Created VPC " + vpcId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sébastien Stormacq for supporting me with your answer. We have found the solution for this issue. Actually my windows desktop time was 6 minutes late to the actual time. So there its getting the conflict to validate the AWS credentials. We synced the time manually with exact time and now its working like a charm. Please once check the Windows time when one is getting the same issue.